# Mysql time range in other time range

Tags: mysql, time, range

Hi all and sorry for my bad english...

I must select hour range in a time that is not included in other time range...
For example, this is the table

```
DATE        | Time_from | Time_to | Hour
01/01/2015    10:00       18:00     8
02/01/2015    08:00       20:00     12
02/01/2015    16:00       19:00     3
```

For date 02/01/2015 I must get only row 2 with 12 hour because time range of row 3 is included in row 2 ...

Hope I explained well...

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this

```
select a.date
from table a
where not exists (select b.date from table b
                  where a.date = b.date and
                  ((a.Time_from >= b.Time_from and a.Time_from <= b.Time_to) or
                   (a.Time_to >= b.Time_from and a.Time_to <= b.Time_to))
```

**EDIT**
You also need to exclude the the row being worked on in table `a` from table `b` by adding something using unique id

```
and a.uniqueid <> b.uniqeid
```

Comment: Can be a solution but I must change something... Time_to can be on next day and then for example time_from <= time_to doesn't work

Thanks anyway

Comment: If the answer works for you then you should tick it as the correct answer to indicate that it does.